# How to render the contents of angular variables inside ng-bind-html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-bind-html, ng-bind

I'm taking a HTML content to the front end javascript code, from the database which was saved as varchar. It is stored in a variable called `vm.htmlContent` And then I want to display this string type HTML content again as HTML in my web page. I use `ng-bind-html` angular directive for doing this. My HTML content which is stored in `vm.htmlContent` variable is:

```
<p> Date: </ p> <p> Time: </ p> <p> Venue: </ p>
```

The current javascript code for this is looks like:

```
<ng-bind-html
    ng bind-html="vm.htmlContent">
 </ng-bind-html>
```

the output in the web page is:

```
Date:
Time:
Venue:
```

I want to add Date,Time and venue from other angular variables inside this `ng-bind-html.` The date,time and venue variables are `vm.date`,`vm.time` and `vm.venue` and they keep the relevant data clearly. **Is there a way to do this without spiting the string content in `vm.htmlContent` variable**?

Comment: Is using the `htmlContent` variable even necessary here? Unless I'm missing something, seems like you could render the other three variables with the "Date:", "Time:", etc. text yourself

Comment: The html content is taking from the database and it is stored in `vm.htmlContent` variable. I can't just type the text by myself in the javascript code. It has to be come from the database and for storing it I use `vm.htmlContent` variable. So that is the usage of it

Answer (score 0):

A few `.replace()` calls would be a fairly straight-forward way of getting those variables in there:

```
vm.getReplacedContent = () => {
  return vm.htmlContent
    .replace('Date:', `Date: ${vm.date}`)
    .replace('Time:', `Time: ${vm.time}`)
    .replace('Venue:', `Venue: ${vm.venue}`)
}

<div ng-bind-html="vm.getReplacedContent()"></div>
```

Though I'm not experienced with angular, and I'm not sure if the HTML will automatically update doing things this way. If it *doesn't* update, instead of a function, you might have to use another scope variable and `$watch` the `vm.htmlContent` variable to update it.

Comment: Exactly same idea provided by me with using angular

Answer (score 0):

Try this way by using replace

```js
    
    
  angular.module("myApp", []).controller("myCtrl", function($scope,$sce) {
  $scope.date="03/07/2018";
  $scope.time="1.00 PM";
  $scope.venue="US"
  $scope.myTexts = "<p> Date: </ p> <p> Time: </ p> <p> Venue: </ p>";
  var replacedData =  $scope.myTexts.replace("Date:","Date:" + $scope.date).replace("Time:","Time:" + $scope.time).replace("Venue:","Venue: " + $scope.venue);
  $scope.myText = $sce.trustAsHtml(replacedData);      
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
 <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">    
        <p ng-bind-html="myText"></p>    
 </div>
```